# Why do I get error in import of matplotlib.animation?

Tags: matplotlib, animation

Using python 3.7,

import matplotlib.animation as animation
.
.
.
CalledProcessError: Command '['convert', '--version']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.

Comment: You need a working version of the `convert` executable from imagemagick.  Try it from the command line if in doubt.

Comment: Used "brew install imagemagick" - now works fine - thanks anyway